# Rails. Filter Postgres objects by their Arrays. ERROR: malformed array literal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Cant deal with array filtering. This:

```
@profiles = Profile.filter(params.slice(:location, :status, :items))
```

Passes records to be filtered:

```
def filter(filtering_params)
  results = self.where(nil)
  puts filtering_params

  filtering_params.each do |key, value|
    if value.is_a?(Array)     
      results = results.public_send(key, value.to_s) if self.where("#{key}", value)
    else
      results = results.public_send(key, value) if value.present? 
    end
  end
  results
end
```

But there are some problems with Postgres Array. Params passed to `filter` method are:

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "location"=>"0", "status"=>"0",
>   "items"=>["0", "1"], "commit"=>"Filtruoti"}

and method receives them:

> {"location"=>"0", "status"=>"0", "items"=>["0", "1"]}

But I get error:

> PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "0"
>   LINE 1: ..." = $2 AND "profiles"."items" IN ('0', '1')
>   ...                                                        ^
>
> DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information. :
>   SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE
>   "profiles"."location" = $1 AND
>   "profiles"."status" = $2 AND
>   "profiles"."items" IN ('0', '1') LIMIT $3 OFFSET $4

And this error actually points to where I want to display received records:

`<% rofiles.each do |profile| %>`

What is happening with this Postgres Array..?

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.3'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
```

EDIT:

Looks like t works well now with scope:

```
scope :items, -> (items) { where "items && ARRAY[?]::integer[]", items }
```

And:

```
def filter(filtering_params)
  results = self.where(nil)

  filtering_params.each do |key, value|
    puts value
    if value.is_a?(Array)     
      value = [0, 1, 2]
      results = results.public_send(key, value) if self.where("key && ARRAY[?]::integer[]", value)
    else
      results = results.public_send(key, value) if value.present? 
    end
  end
  results
end
```

Comment: The `profiles.items` column is an array of integers and you want the query to find rows whose `items` contain `1` or `0`?

Comment: @mu is too short, with the code above I tried to find only those that holds both of them. But now I actually need items that contains any of them :) And my column is array of strings, for now.. `["0", "1"]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ActiveRecord does not automatically create queries for array type columns.

Querying an array column can be done with:

```
Profile.where("items@> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", ["0", "1"])
# or 
Profile.where("items@> ARRAY[?]::integer[]", [0, 1])
```

But if items is a model in your application you should create a join table instead. Arrays are not a replacement for relational data modeling.

- [Active Record and PostgreSQL](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array)

Comment: Oh, could you tell if this leaves any SQL or XSS injection possibilities? AFAIK, we must be careful with `where` and Arrays. I think I am relatively secure, because these runs `GET`, not `POST` - am I?

Comment: This uses a parametized query. The `?` is replaced by the values passed by the db so it is not vulnerable in the same way that  `"items@> ARRAY[<%= params[:some_param] %>]::integer[]"` would be as a the DB will reject the values instead of executing arbitrary SQL.

Comment: "I think I am relatively secure, because these runs GET, not POST - am I?" - nope you're just very wrong. The HTTP method does not matter when it comes to SQL injections.

Comment: POST is only really more secure for the client. If the client is on a unsecure public network and SSL (https) is not used it leaves the client vulnerable to traffic sniffing where an attacker can see what url was requested and thus any GET params. But this has nothing to do with SQL injections which is caused by inserting user provided data straight into a SQL string.

Comment: Ok, I felt like this before asking does GET matters :) But better be sure. And shouldn't I escape or sanitize that array, passed to `where`?  I've read just a bit about this and that was a little confusing to understand - how array items being escaped in Rails

Comment: The array can't really contain anything except strings or integers or simple scalar types. And postgres will reject the value if it is does not match the type given in the query. The values are also properly quoted so even if someone tried to sneak in `DROP TABLE "users";` it is not executed by the DB.

Comment: oh, that makes sense - thats why we must cast type in query.. Thanks @max, once again - you saved the day!

Comment: Postgres requires a type anyways when you query arrays, hstore and hashes.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a different approach:

- Firstly, made `Profile.items` a column of JSONB type.
- Added a scope:

  ```
  scope :has_item, -> (item) { where(%{ items::jsonb ?& array[:item] }, item: item) }
  ```
- Finally, used it as follows:

  ```
  Profile.has_item(:item_a)

  # or

  Profile.has_item([:item_a, :item_b])
  ```